# I can't put user input in my JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, illegalargumentexception

I'm using Netbeans so I'm using the drag and drop interface for creating the GUI.

This is my code:

```
    if (MenuOrder.BURGER == 1)
    {   
        tableSalesFood.setValueAt("Cheeseburger",FastFoodProper.rowCount,0);
        tableSalesFood.setValueAt("80.00",FastFoodProper.rowCount,2);
    }

    if (MenuOrder.FRIES == 1)
    {   
        tableSalesFood.setValueAt("French Fries",FastFoodProper.rowCount,0);
        tableSalesFood.setValueAt("40.00",FastFoodProper.rowCount,2);
    }

    if (MenuOrder.CHICKEN == 1)
    {   
        tableSalesFood.setValueAt("Chicken w/Rice",FastFoodProper.rowCount,0);
        tableSalesFood.setValueAt("100.00",FastFoodProper.rowCount,2);
    }

    if (MenuOrder.SALAD == 1)
    {   
        tableSalesFood.setValueAt("Caesar Salad",FastFoodProper.rowCount,0);
        tableSalesFood.setValueAt("90.00",FastFoodProper.rowCount,2);
    }

    if (MenuOrder.PIZZA == 1)
    {   
        tableSalesFood.setValueAt("Pepperoni Pizza",FastFoodProper.rowCount,0);
        tableSalesFood.setValueAt("300.00",FastFoodProper.rowCount,2);
    }

    if (MenuOrder.ONION == 1)
    {   
        tableSalesFood.setValueAt("Onion Rings",FastFoodProper.rowCount,0);
        tableSalesFood.setValueAt("50.00",FastFoodProper.rowCount,2)
    } rowCount++;
```

It returns with an error : Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number

However, when I remove the bottom part that displays the price, it works. But my programming project requires it to display both the food description and price. How would I do that?

Comment: You are using values like  `"50.00"`. These are Strings. The Exception tells, that you are trying to use those as numbered values. Can you try to remove the quotes?

Comment: which line you by mistake?

Comment: What type did you declare for that part of your table?
Another thing that I see, is that you use an enum (I think) MenuOrder.
In there you have multiple flags with what the orders could be.
Isn't it better to have one integer with just one value for each meal?
Because right now it is possible to have multiple values.
If you do not agree with me, at least have a look at the ifs you use.
In this case I think you would rather use if and else, so that the value is not overwritten if multiple of the meals are possible.